# How can I use an USB-stick as an CD-disc?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, compact-disc

I'm currently using Ubuntu (11.04), and I'd like to use an USB-stick as a CD-disc to "burn" the JNode operating system on it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create bootable USB sticks for installing various Linux distros from (or to use live).

Comment: Indeed! Big thx

Comment: The tool does a lot of the work that I need, but doesn't work with JNode... However, for other Ubuntu Distro's, it works great!

Answer (score 3):

[Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) is a great tool that allows you to make bootable usb sticks. It also has a built in list of Operating Systems (including all of the Ubuntu variants) and bootable tools that you can pick, download, and then add to the boot menu.  It is extremely simple to use and within a few clicks you can have a bootable usb stick with multiple OSes and tools to choose from on boot.

You can also choose your own isos that are not on the list.

Answer (score 2):

[HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/) providing a complete tutorial on this that how can you install the Ubuntu through USB stick. [Ubuntu Forum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) also provide the detail about this method. Hope you will find them useful.